# Trying to read invalid data from array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, memory

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    string str = "5 7 3";
    int length = str.length();
    char* arr = new char[length];
    cout << arr[2] << endl;
    /*
    int max = stoi(string(1, arr[0]));
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(arr[i] != ' '){
            if (stoi(string(1, arr[i])) > max) {
                max = stoi(string(1, arr[i]));
            }
        }
    }
    cout << max << endl;
    */
    

delete[] arr;
}
```

I'm getting error C6385 " Reading invalid data" when I'm trying to cout arr[2]. When I'm trying to cout arr[0], for instance, I get char 'H' in console, I don't really understand why is there 'H' if I don't have H in my str

Comment: arr is empty. where you are filling the arr with any kind of info?

Comment: `arr` is a char array with length 5, but unknown content. `H` is just random garbage in your memory at that time.

Comment: why shouldn't it be an H? where is the part that makes it not an H?

Answer (score 3):

```
char* arr = new char[length];
cout << arr[2] << endl;
```

These are the only lines that matter for your question. The first one allocates a character array. The data stored in the array at this pointer is unknown. It could be zeroes, it could be complete garbage. In your case, there happens to sometimes be an 'H' in index 2. If you run it in a hour it could be different - likely the last thing stored at the memory address of that array element had an ascii value of H.

Answer (score 1):

`arr[]` doesn't contain your str because you didn't do anything for that to happen. Also, to fit the `string` content , you would need `new char[length + 1]` to account for terminating zero.

After all, you don't need convert a string to an array in most cases, a string already contains i. There is `std::stoi` function that works with strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
char* arr = new char[length];
```

that means, reseve memory and call it *arr, it as memory as lenght* char* size, this memory can conteins another runtime var or something unreadable for C++, so when u try:

```
cout << arr[2] << endl;
```

If u can read it, it will give you that value, as 'H', but if u cant it should get nothing or strange icon.

Just reboot PC and you arent going to get another 'H' on your arr[0]

Anyway as your code looks u need to change it:

```
char* arr = new char[length];
cout << arr[2] << endl;
```

for:

```
char* arr = new char[length + 1];
```